# Drawing some circles with UIBezierPath

Tags: swift, for-loop, uibezierpath

I would like to draw some circles with UIBezierPath. I've got an array of points: `pointsXY = [(35.625, 20.01), (71.25, 60.03), (106.875, 100.05), (142.5, 140.07), (320.625, 180.09)]`
I've tried for loop and then using .stroke() inside draw:

```
for i in pointsXY{
    pointsOnChart = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: i, radius: CGFloat(2), startAngle: CGFloat(0), endAngle: CGFloat(2*Double.pi), clockwise: false)
}

override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    UIColor.white.set()
    pointsOnChart.stroke()
}
```

The result is that only the last point appears in the UIView. I don't know why is it a problem, because in the same way I managed to draw lines (inside for loop with .move() and .addLine())

Comment: `pointsOnChart` is REPLACED each time you loop. So you'll get only the last one.

Comment: that's weird because I did the same thing with UIBezierPath to draw a line with .move and .addLline inside a loop and .stroke() worked and didn't get replaced. What is the easiest way to get this done? Should I create the array of UIBezierPath and loop it inside func draw?

Comment: `override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) { UIColor.white.set() for i in pointsXY{ let pointsOnChart = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: i, radius: CGFloat(2), startAngle: CGFloat(0), endAngle: CGFloat(2*Double.pi), clockwise: false); pointsOnChart.stroke()}}`? And `.move() and .addLine()`it's not a `init` method, it modify the current path, not set its value.

Comment: @Larme that makes sense, thanks!